# Unable to use jQuery form validation plugin inside an Angular app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, jquery-validate

I have recently upgraded my site to a Single-page-application configuration using AngularJS. Ever since Im not able to use `jQuery form validation plugin`. I have included all the needed files and checked that the path is correct, but seems like the validation is made in the browser, rather than in my code.

The application is divided to several HTML files, which are dynamically injected into `index.html`. The order which I included the required files is:

- All `CSS` files are loaded in the `Head`, then some code, including `<div ng-view></div>`.
- Then I load the JS files: jquery, jquery validation, jquery form pluging.

```js
/*validate contact form */
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            inputName: {
                required: "name needed!",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: "email needed!"
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: "content required!"
            }
        },//submits the data to the php file using ajax request
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#contactForm').ajaxSubmit({

                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"index2.php",
                success: function() {
                    $("#contactForm").hide(1000);
                    $("#feedback").html("Message sent!").addClass("success");
                    createDymanicButton();
                },
                error: function() {
                    $("#contactForm").hide(1000);
                    $("#feedback").html("There was an error, please try again later").addClass("failure");

                    createDymanicButton();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myModal" target=_self role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="modal">form</a>   
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
          </div>
          <!-- end modal-header -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>contact form</p>
            <hr>
            <!-- **************** the Form starts here *********-->
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your name" type="text" value="" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="your@email.com" type="email" value="" required>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="3" required></textarea>
                  <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
          <!-- end modal-body -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--the footer that will include some feedback-->
            <div id="feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of modal footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- end modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- end modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- end myModal -->
```

The form, which requires the validation is located inside `home.html` file.
I tried placing the custom JS file and the jQuery in the beginning of the `home.html`, but no matter what I try the browser is the only thing that is validating my form.

Please advise

Comment: Can you provide us your HTML form?

Comment: Thanks, I added the HTML code for the form

Comment: @undroid bootstrap doesn't work without jQuery, please add the jQuery scripts back.

Comment: Yeah sorry bout that, didnt pay attention. Anyways now its all there.

Comment: This demo seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Why jquery validation? Angular 1.3+ brings everything in the toolset.

Comment: @undroid also, I'm not sure if this is intentional or not but your function call says ``createDymanicButton()`` instead of ``createDynamicButton()``.

Comment: Partick, the form is being validated in the browser, not in the custom code I provided.

EDIT - yes this is intentional, this is a custom function i made.

Fals, maybe I will use Angular in the next iteration, meanwhile I want to make this work using jQuery.

Comment: Why do you keep saying validation is provided by the browser?  The snippet you provided above is absolutely using the jQuery Validation plugin as evidenced by your error messages.

Comment: The snippet works if the site is built as ONE HTML block, in my site this doesnt work. The site is divided into several HTML files which dynamically loaded into the `index.html` template (as SPA works), depending on the user selection. This form code is located inside `home.html` file, the validation never happens with this configuration..

Answer (score 8):

I created a bridge between AngularJS and the jQuery Validation Plugin. It validates a form using a single directive `ng-validate`, which automatically detects when the DOM is ready.

Give it a try: https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate. Feedback is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sir, its a wonderful Plugin. Only problem I am facing is how to apply css in your plugin.? Please guide me on this.

Comment: Hi @Steve, You can use [setDefaults](https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate#default-validation-options) to set things like [errorclass](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorclass) and [validClass](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#validclass). Then you can apply css styling to those classes.

Comment: Yes it worked,thank you sir. but now I am facing another problem. How to remove all error on form reset? please guide me on this sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your difficulty was. I copied your snippet and added the validation code to it, and it seems to work exactly like you wanted it to.

```js
/*validate contact form */
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            inputName: {
                required: "name needed!",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: "email needed!"
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: "content required!"
            }
        },//submits the data to the php file using ajax request
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#contactForm').ajaxSubmit({

                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"index2.php",
                success: function() {
                    $("#contactForm").hide(1000);
                    $("#feedback").html("Message sent!").addClass("success");
                    createDymanicButton();
                },
                error: function() {
                    $("#contactForm").hide(1000);
                    $("#feedback").html("There was an error, please try again later").addClass("failure");

                    createDymanicButton();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myModal" target=_self role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="modal">form</a>   
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
          </div>
          <!-- end modal-header -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>contact form</p>
            <hr>
            <!-- **************** the Form starts here *********-->
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your name" type="text" value="" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="your@email.com" type="email" value="" required>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="3" required></textarea>
                  <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
          <!-- end modal-body -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--the footer that will include some feedback-->
            <div id="feedback"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of modal footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- end modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- end modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- end myModal -->
```

Put jquery, then jquery.validate, then jquery.form, then bootstrap, then your validation code. If you want to force them to load in order, put the jquery, jquery.validate, jquery.form, and bootstrap in the `<head>`. This will load them in order, but no HTML is rendered until they are all finished loading, which slows down your page loading time. The custom validation code should go in the `<body>`, though it's up to you where since it's wrapped in jQuery's `document.ready` function (the `$(function () {...});`).

Comment: This code used to work as intended until i divided my up into several `HTML` files (to inject dynamically content), now it seems my JS file is not the one who's responsible for the validation of the form. In what order did you add the `jquery/js` files in your IDE? I wamt my custom text to appear, instead of the browsers default one.

Comment: @undroid Make sure you call `$('#contactForm').validate()`  after all your views in angular have been rendered. I'm guesssing you'll find that `$('#contactForm').length` is zero when you call it

Comment: Patrick, no avail..
Juan, the length is 1, so i guess all was loaded.. but just in case, how can i be sure that it was really loaded before i call the validate function?

Answer (score 0):

i thought you can refer this link for your reference which is used jquery.validate.js plugin in angularjs application 
https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/PzBNBY

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/PzBNBY)
     //form validation using Angularjs and jquery.validate.js with ui.bootstrap       and ui.utils

```
  var app=angular.module('formvalid', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.utils']);
  app.controller('validationCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.validationOpt = {
      rules: {
         name: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 3
         },
         urlfield: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 3,
           url: true
        },dropdown:{
          required:{
          depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#dropdown").val() == '';
                 }
        }
       },'test[]': {
         required: true,
          minlength:2
       },
        namecallback:{
          required:true,
          callBackFunction:function(value,element){
            //business logic functions
          }
       }
    },
    messages: {
        'test[]': {
            required: "You must check at least 1 box",
            maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes",
            minlength:"Pleace check {0} boxes"
        }
   },    
   submitHandler : function() {
      $("#formid").validate().resetForm();  
      $('#formid')[0].reset();
     //for multipart
      /*    $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            },
            data : formData,
            transformRequest : function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                return data;
            }
            }).success(function(response) {
                msg = response.data;
                type = "success";     
            }).error(function(response) {
                msg = response.data;
               type = "error"
            });*/
         }
       };  
       $scope.data=[{id:1,name:"One"},{id:2,name:"two"},    {id:3,name:"three"}];
      $scope.formsubmit=function(){
     //alert("hai");
      }
    });


    <div class="container" ng-app="formvalid">
      <div class="panel" data-ng-controller="validationCtrl">
      <div class="panel-heading border">    
      <h2>Form validation using Angularjs  and jquery.validate</h2>
   </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <form id="formid" role="form" ui-jq="validate" ui-options="validationOpt" ng-submit="formsubmit()">
    <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p> drop down box validation with </p>
    <div>
      <select class="form-control" name="dropdown" ng-model="dropdown"  id="dropdown">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
        <option ng-repeat="i in data" value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p> check box validations</p>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />x
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />y
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />z

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | minimum length 3 characters</p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namecallback" placeholder="Required | minimum length 3 characters">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | valid email format</p>
    <div>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Required | valid email format" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | valid url format</p>
    <div>
      <input type="url" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Required | valid url format" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | number</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Required | number" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | number | min 10</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" min="10" class="form-control" name="number-min" placeholder="Required | number | min 10" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | number | max 10</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" max="10" class="form-control" name="number-max" placeholder="Required | number | max 10" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mb25">
    <p>Required | number | min 0 | max 100</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" name="number-num" placeholder="Required | number | min 0 | max 100" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary mr10">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```